# ROS Basics: Setting up my first project

Tags: lidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just want to make sure I'm understanding the setup properly. Maybe I'm missing something but I feel like there is a bit of a gap in the tutorial between where you are building essentially an empty project, and where they have you call premade functions/packages.

Lets say I want to start experimenting with LIDAR mapping using Hector SLAM (I don't have access to an odometer at the moment). I see the sicktoolbox_wrapper, hector_slam and gmapping packages. Would I just rosmake and rosrun those from where they are(which is what it looks like the tutorial is doing) or would I build my own project using:

roscreate-pkg LIDAR_testing sicktoolbox gmapping hector_slam etc etc
rosmake LIDAR_testing

and go from there?

I'm using Groovy on Ubuntu 12.04.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/56319/ros-basics:-setting-up-my-first-project/) by [Rudolf](https://answers.ros.org/users/4300/rudolf/) on ROS Answers with karma: 3 on 2013-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If ur using the above mentioned packages without any modifications then you can just write a launch file to start them together.

---

Originally posted by [ayush_dewan](https://answers.ros.org/users/2268/ayush_dewan/) with karma: 1610 on 2013-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1